# why video tag is getting loaded again when i call method on timeupdate in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

So I have `<video>` tag in my html code and I am getting source for that video tag by calling method and also i am calling one method on timeupdate. video tag is as below

```
<video id="video" [src]="content.iframeUrl(0)" (timeupdate)="internal()" height="100%" width="100%" controls autoplay value="aaa" #test>
```

method iframeUrl() is as below:

```
iframeUrl(tab){
var src=[]; 
for(let a of this.paths){
  src[0]=a.content_video;
  src[1]=a.description;
  src[2]=a.quiz;
  src[3]=a._3dobject;
  src[4]=a.prerequisites;
  src[5]=a.current_research;
  src[6]=a.history;
  src[7]=a.faq;
}
var url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(src[tab]);
return url;
}
```

and internal() is as below:

```
internal(){                                                                     
  for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) /*The for loop to check for the conditions. 21 stops total*/
  {
      if(this.vid.currentTime >= this.time[i] && this.bools[i] == false) {
      this.vid.pause();
      this.bools[i] = true;
      this.vid.style.display="none";
      this.quiz.style.display="block";
  }
  // console.log(a);
 }
```

}

But iframeUrl is getting called continuously. How to stop that?